# pass javascript variable to controller in rails 3.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

```
<script> var depart_date='11 February 2013';
         var depart_date='21 February 2013';
</script>


    jQuery.ajax({

data: { depart: depart_date, return_date: return_date},
    type: 'post',
  url: "/payment/create",

});
```

This is my ajax call.

In terminal it's value getting as {"depart"=>"11 February 2013", "return_date"=>"21 February 2013"}

But in controller  params[:depart] & params[:return] shows as `nil` value.

Can an one help me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: from your code data: 'depart=' + depart_date,
Try to look into params[:depart]

Comment: Are you sure depart_date is populated when you send it? Also, you could try `{ depart: depart_data}` instead of `'depart=' + depart_date`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. but this doen't solve problem.getting nil value

Comment: In your controller, can you add a logging statement to see if the params hash contains anything related? Can you check the network tab in Chrome or FF to verify that the AJAX call actually contains the depart_date in the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax to the following

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/payment/create",                     // you to pass this as the url option
  type: 'post',
  data: 'depart=' + depart_date,
  dataType: 'script',                         // this should be dataType, not dateType
  success: function() { alert('success') }    // this should be a function
});
```